# How do I search in Windows File Explorer for files beginning with a hyphen?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

I've tried the following: `-`, `-*`, `-*.*`, `"-"`, `"-*"`, `"-*.*"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an escape character sequence followed by the symbol you are looking for in quotes. It would look like this:

`~="-"`

You can also try pasting this into the search box:

`filename:- -kind:folder`
This will search filenames beginning with a hyphen and NOT include foldernames, just files.

In powershell, you can run the command: [Picture of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9K4z.png)

**Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Include `-* -Recurse fl | Name,Directory**

This will list all files starting with a hyphen.

**The easiest way:**

The commands to find files solely on starting character do not exist under the [Advanced Search Query Syntax:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(VS.85).aspx) . The easiest way was to download [Everything by Void Tools](http://www.voidtools.com/) and then enter "-*" in the search box without quotes. Here is a [screenshot of the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeMZh.png)

Comment: Thank you, but: your first answer finds all those that contain a hyphen, not just those that begin with one. Your second answer doesn't work at all - I simply see all files.

Comment: @wezten What version of windows are you on? They search functions changed between 7 and 10. I will try to modify my answer to include a few more methods.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: So, I couldn't get it to work on 10, and apparently, the commands to find files solely on starting character do not exist under the [Advanced Search Query Syntax:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(VS.85).aspx) . The easiest way was to download [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) by void tools and then enter "-*" in the search box without quotes. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/M0bTvbl.png) of the results.

Comment: @wezten added a few more methods